# Suspense React not working on fetching data

Tags: reactjs, promise, fetch, fetch-api

I'am trying to use Suspense to render a fallback while the Promise is not solved. What am I doing wrong?

It's supposed to render the fallback while the fetch promise don't return the data. But when i try to fetch the data from the browser the fallback does not appear.

```
export const MainFlow = () => {
    const URL_BASE = 'https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search'
    const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([])

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await httpService.request({
            url: `${URL_BASE}?limit=10`,
            method: 'get',
            headers: { 'x-api-key': 'some-key' }
        })
        setData(response.body)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const DogImage: FC<DogImageProps> = ({ url }) => {
        return (
            <img src={url} alt="I'am a doggo." className="mfone__dog-images" />
        )
    }

    return (
        <div id="mfone__dog-container">
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <div id="mfone__images-box">
                    {data
                        ? data.map((element, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <DogImage key={index} url={element.url} />
                                )
                          })
                        : null}
                </div>
            </Suspense>
            <div id="mfone__links-box">
                <Link to="/" className="mfone__dog-links">
                    Back to Home page
                </Link>
                <button
                    onClick={() => fetchData()}
                    className="mfone__dog-links"
                >
                    More Doggos
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried to put the Suspense tag inside the div that has the id "*mfone__images-box*", but still not working:

```
return (
        <div id="mfone__dog-container">
            <div id="mfone__images-box">
                <Suspense fallback={<div>Carregando...</div>}>
                    {data
                        ? data.map((element, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <DogImage key={index} url={element.url} />
                                )
                          })
                        : null}
                </Suspense>
            </div>
            <div id="mfone__links-box">
                <Link to="/" className="mfone__dog-links">
                    Back to Home page
                </Link>
                <button
                    onClick={() => fetchData()}
                    className="mfone__dog-links"
                >
                    More Doggos
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, `Suspense` only works when implementing lazy loading of a component, it doesn't support your use case which is data fetching. In this case, you could create a loading state which is set to `true` as soon as the data fetching function starts executing and then, set to `false` once it completes, that way you can display the loading/fetching UI based on that state.

**Update:** `Suspense` can now be used for data fetching purposes when implementing React Server Components, which have moved from experimental into full support. [Next.js v13](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs) has started implementing React Server Components in its still experimental `app` directory feature.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that Suspense doesn't work without lazy load...